# How do I extract extension of a file within a directory?

Tags: bash, macos, unix

The directory's name is known, and it is known that all the files in this directory have the same extension. I need only to extract one extension and assign it to a variable.

I have a script that takes different routines depending on the content of a directory. If, for example, the folder contains `jpg` files, the script performs different actions on `tiff` files. My script does not need to know the names of the files, or the numbers, only their extensions. So I need to extract an extension of any one of the files (all files have the same extension), and assign it to a variable.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
variable=$(basename "/path/dir/*")
extension="${variable##*.}"
```

where `"*"` wildcard lists all the files. I need only one extension.

Comment: What do you mean determine the extension of an unkown file? There is the `file` command which tells you the type of file. Are you asking for a bash script that extracts just the extension of a given filename?

Comment: directory is known, filename is unknown and does not need to know the name or how many there are. Only one of the file extension needed in my script.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the directory contents and what you need available in the script?

Comment: And when you provide examples, please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40713048/edit) rather than answering in the comments. Your question is incomplete as it stands. Check the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines for everything you need to make it a great question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension=$(ls directory_path/ | awk -F. 'NR==1{print $NF}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` to find the extension.

```
for file in directory/*.*; do
    var=$(echo $file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} {print $NF}')
    break
done
```

In this example, FS tells awk to use the period "." to separate fields, and $NF specifies the last field.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it gives me a syntax error   "syntax error near unexpected token `do'".

Comment: Strange. You might move "do" to it;s own line and remove the semi-colon from the end of the first line, to see if that changes anything. Also note that I had to edit the example because I forgot the final single-quote in line two, so make sure you tried the updated version. If nothing else works, try posting the exact command you're running (directory text and all)?

Comment: Thanks it did work. I guess was missing " ' " after {print $NF} .

Answer (score 0):

```
file=$(find directory -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print -quit)
ext="${file##*.}"
```

The `find` command finds the first file in `directory`, prints the path and quits. The result (path) is written to the `file` variable.

The next line removes longest match of `*.` from the front of the path, and assigns the result to the `ext` variable.

Adjust the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` options as appropriate.